# Logic app run successful but didnt pickup data

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps

I have a logic app which runs daily. It is connected to db. So each day it picks up data and for each record it trigger emails. But for a few days randomly, it has not picked data. Even though in azure I see this logic app run has not failed any day, but no email was triggered for some days in between (like on 27 aug and 1 sept in past 30 days). Please help. How can I check the reason of this issue?

Comment: What action is used to pick up data from your DB?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue with a logic app that is triggered by a new email. The fix for me was deleting and redeploying the logic app and running the trigger manually.

Edit the trigger in the portal first, then run the trigger manually to see if it works.

Comment: No, we can't run it manually. As this is running from years and it has to continue like this

Comment: Is there a way for you to test in lower environment? Re-create the logic app there with the same triggers and pointing to the same db? Can you also check if there are other services connecting to the same database connection - another logic app maybe? It will also be helpful to check the database status. It might be down

Comment: on lower environment also, for some random dates it has happened like this. But works properly for rest dates. Recreating the same might not help, because we don't know when this issue will happen again. I checked one more logic app which runs at same time, and it has proper data, so we are sure that DB was not down at that moment.

Comment: I see, best to raise a ticket to microsoft so they can have this checked because it happens to most logic apps. :(